# NSString indexOf in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there anything similar to an `indexOf` function in the NSString objects?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use `-[NSString rangeOfString:]`:

```
- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString;
```

> Finds and returns the range of the first occurrence of a given string within the receiver.

Comment: And `NSRange.location` is the actual index.

Comment: `if (NSRange.location != NSNotFound)` then you found a match.

Answer (score 29):

If you want just know when String a contains String b use my way to do this.

```
#define contains(str1, str2) ([str1 rangeOfString: str2 ].location != NSNotFound)

//using 
NSString a = @"PUC MINAS - BRAZIL";

NSString b = @"BRAZIL";

if( contains(a,b) ){
    //TO DO HERE
}
```

This is less readable but improves performance

Answer (score 19):

I wrote a category to extend original NSString object. Maybe you guys can reference it.
(You also can see the [article](http://fstoke.me/blog/?p=3121) in my blog too.)

ExtendNSString.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (util)

- (int) indexOf:(NSString *)text;

@end
```

ExtendNSStriing.m:

```
#import "ExtendNSString.h"

@implementation NSString (util)

- (int) indexOf:(NSString *)text {
    NSRange range = [self rangeOfString:text];
    if ( range.length > 0 ) {
        return range.location;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: A better usage of NSRange should be as follows
`code`
- (int) indexOf:(NSString *)text {
    NSRange range = [self rangeOfString:text];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        return range.location;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
`code`

Comment: Nice, clean, reuseable solution.  And voted -1 to Apple for still making us having to write such blatantly simple helper functions in 2014. Why can't they make life easier for us?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late, but I added a category that implements this method and many others similar to javascript string methods
https://github.com/williamFalcon/WF-iOS-Categories