# How to find substring containing @ symbol in iOS

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, ipad, nsstring

I've searched and searched, and because the "@" symbol is used in strings (ex: @"mystring") in iOS, I cannot find how to determine whether a string contains it. Once I determine if it contains it, I need to know its location within the string.

```
NSArray *array_Email_Parts = [str_Email_Address componentsSeparatedByString: @"//@"];
```

The above doesn't work. I've tried several variations of it. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can escape special characters with a backslash, so maybe try `@"\@"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSString indexOf in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256460/nsstring-indexof-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will get the index of the `@` symbol.

```
NSString *email = @"user@example.com";
NSRange range = [email rangeOfString:@"@"];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"Location of @ is %i", range.location);
    // Prints "Location of @ is 4"
}
```

Note that `@` is perfectly valid within an `NSString`, don't escape it.

```
NSArray *parts = [email componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
if ([parts count] == 2) {
    NSString *user = [parts objectAtIndex:0];   // equal to "user"
    NSString *domain = [parts objectAtIndex:1]; // equal to "example.com"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get what you are actually asking but i think you're looking for this:

```
if ([myString rangeOfString:@"@"].location != NSNotFound)
    //myString contains @
else
    //myString does not contain @
```

If you are having trouble with the @ in the string try @@