# iOS: extract substring of NSString in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have an `NSString` as:

```
"<a href='javascript:void(null)' onclick='handleCommandForAnchor(this, 10);return false;'>12321<\/a>"
```

I need to extract the 12321 near the end of the `NSString` from it and store.
First I tried

```
        NSString *shipNumHtml=[mValues objectAtIndex:1];
        NSInteger htmlLen=[shipNumHtml length];

        NSString *shipNum=[[shipNumHtml substringFromIndex:htmlLen-12]substringToIndex:8];
```

But then I found out that number 12321 can be of variable length.

I can't find a method like java's `indexOf()` to find the `'>'` and `'<'` and then find substring with those indices. All the answers I've found on SO either know what substring to search for or know the location if the substring. Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSString indexOf in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256460/nsstring-indexof-in-objective-c)

Comment: yup, you can use rangeOfString:

Comment: you *could* use `rangeOfString`, but youd be better off using `NSScanner`

Comment: maybe a regular expression related question? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't usually advocate using Regular expressions for parsing HTML contents but it seems a regex matching `>(\d+)<` would to the job in this simple string.

Here is a simple example:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@">(\\d+)<"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                         error:&error];
// Handle error != nil

NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:string
                                                options:0
                                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
if (match) {
    NSRange matchRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSString *number = [string substringWithRange:matchRange]
    NSLog(@"Number: %@", number);
}
```

Comment: This seems like it would help. How can I search for a regex in an NSString?

Comment: Just added an example (not tested)

Answer (score 1):

As @HaneTV says, you can use the NSString method rangeOfString to search for substrings. Given that the characters ">" and "<" appear in multiple places in your string, so you might want to take a look at NSRegularExpression and/or NSScanner.

Answer (score -1):

that may help on you a bit, I've just tested:

```
NSString *_string = @"<a href='javascript:void(null)' onclick='handleCommandForAnchor(this, 10);return false;'>12321</a>";
NSError *_error;
NSRegularExpression *_regExp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@">(.*)<" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&_error];
NSArray *_matchesInString = [_regExp matchesInString:_string options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, _string.length)];
[_matchesInString enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult * result, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    for (int i = 0; i < result.numberOfRanges; i++) {
        NSString *_match = [_string substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:i]];
        NSLog(@"%@", _match);
    }
}];
```